# CQ5 SlingServlet and resourceTypes not working for specific resource paths

Tags: servlets, aem, sling

If I define a Sling Servlet as follows:

```
@SlingServlet(
    label="TestResourceTypeServlet",
    name = "com.company.project.servlets.TestResourceType",
    extensions = {"bob"},
    resourceTypes= {"cq:Page"},
    methods= {"GET"},
    metatype=true)
@Properties({
@Property(name = "service.description", value = "A test servlet"),
@Property(name = "service.vendor",  value = "Company")
})
```

The servlet picks up any get request to every page with an extension of '.bob', which is fine but what I really want is to handle a request to a specific page type,

**SO**

I modify resourceTypes to read

```
resourceTypes= {"site-administration/components/page/page-distribution"},
```

the supplied value is the specific sling:resourceType (copied and pasted out of CRXDE Lite) of a page I am trying to access with the .bob extension, but I get a 404!!!

All the documentation I've read says the above should work, but it does not.

Out of desperation I've even tried `"site-administration/components/page"` which is the super type of the page I want.

I'm running a clean 5.6.1 instance with this servlet as part of an OSGi bundle.

Am I missing something obvious here, or if not is anyone aware of any hot fixes that could resolve this issue **?**

Any help would be appreciated as I'm starting to go slightly mad in the head.

**EDIT**

Ok, so I've gotten a little further: If I access the page with:

```
[path-to-page]/page.bob.html
```

The servlet fires. But in this URL is `bob` not a selector? and if so why when the resource type is `cq:Page` does the configuration work with bob as an extension?

Very confused :-S

I'm obviously missing something very simple here.

Comment: Strange indeed - if you could share the source code of a minimal bundle that reproduces the problem that would be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with pages is that the resourceType is stored on the jcr:content node below the cq:Page node. If you would call `[path-to-page]/_jcr_content.bob` it should work. Note: `_jcr_content` is an url save version of `jcr:content`.

Why your last example is actually working, I cannot tell.

Comment: Many thanks, that makes sense and works. Do you know if AEM6 is different? When my initial attempts failed I referred to this CQ version 6 page ( https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/resourcetypes.html ) which doesn't mention using jcr:content in the URL. This example configures selectors rather than an extension, but I can't imagine it would make a difference. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: First: ResourceType specific Servlets are great, but make more sense for content components and not whole pages. E.g. if you have an ajax call for a certain component to load more data. Second: Selectors are prefered for pages as usually, you still want to have a well known extension like html, json or xml so the consumer knows what to expect.